# How can i use floating point numbers in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I'm trying to create RGB to YUV converter in VHDL.

```
Y = 0.299 x R + 0.587 x G + 0.114 x B

U = -0.147 x R - 0.289 x G + 0.436 x B

V = 0.615 x R - 0.515 x G -0.100 x B
```

In this formula I have to use and multiple floating point numbers like `0.299`, `0.587`, etc. How do I create synthesizable VHDL with floating point numbers?

Comment: There are IP blocks available, but it's more usually done with fixed point calculations rather than real floats

Comment: There's the IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.11 Floating-point package (float_pkg), but it may likely be done in fixed point using look up tables instead of multiplies depending on the number of R, G, and B bits. Who's synthesis tools/version? What target device/family?

Comment: As @B.Go said: look up how to do fixed point arithmetic. Fixed point arithmetic is exactly the same in all but one aspect as integer calculations. The one aspect is that you have a 'virtual' comma. Basically you multiply all numbers with a power of two, add up and then shift back again by that same power. Some rounding in the end might help too.

Comment: YUV is technically analogue domain. In Digital is it YCbCr

Answer (score 4):

you can this using integer multiplication.

If you have a FPGA with 18 bit multipliers you multiply and then use the upper bits.

E.g. : 0.299, R=20 =>

0.299 * 2^17 = 39191

39191 * 20 then use the result's upper bits ( top downto 17) that is the same as divide by 2^17

Since your application is RGB to YUV I guess this is time critical so the above example is the best choice, otherwise I usually use [Instant SoC](https://www.fpga-cores.com/instant-soc/) to implement float algorithms that is not time critical.