# Converts the temperature expressed in Celsius to Fahrenheit by VHDL

Tags: floating-point, vhdl

I am wondering how to use the data types in VHDL to calculate the formula of Celsius to Fahrenheit(by `b=a*1.8+32`. VHDL doesn't support numbers with decimal points in the synthesis. It needs to output a real type (Fahrenheit) by the integer input(Celsius).

I tried to use the real type, but it couldn't be used in the synthesis except for the simulation part.
This is the part of the codes I wrote:

In synthesis:

```
entity temperature is
    Port ( a : in INTEGER RANGE 82 TO 92;
           b : out INTEGER RANGE 100 TO 300);
end tem;

Architecture Behavioral of temperature is

begin
b<=a*18+320;
end Behavioral;
```

In simulation:

```
signal a: INTEGER;
  signal b: INTEGER;
  signal c: REAL;
  signal d: REAL;
begin

  temperature port map ( a => a,
                      b => b );

  stimulus: process
            variable k: integer:= 0;
  begin
  


a<=82;
c<=82.0;
d<=179.6;
wait for 5 ns;
for k in 0 to 4 loop         

          wait for 5 ns;
          a<= a + 1;
          c<=c+1.0;
          d<=(c+1.0)*1.8+32.0;
        end loop;        
                
        wait;

    wait;
  end process;
```

Comment: Does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58583309/how-can-i-use-floating-point-numbers-in-vhdl) provide any help?

Comment: Apologies if I broke the code too badly trying to fix the question formatting; between the inconsistent indentation and my unfamiliarity with the language I hope I got it right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. You really enlightened me on this issue. Thanks for your time on it.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you deal with numbers in hardware.

1. The implementation of the " * " is dependent on the end product, you might end up using a DSP or implement the multiplication in logic.
2. You need to think how wide are your numbers and select a bit length accordingly.
3. As a general rule, multiplication of a m-bit number with a n-bit number will give a (m+n)bit number. The summation will give max(m,n)+1 bits.
4. If you want to use floating point you need to create the logic for handling such operations, as there are many and the synthesizer won't generate one for you.
5. In this case Fixed Points numbers are fine, as long as you are able to interpret the result. I point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) to an introduction if you are not familiar with them. It also seems that you actually need only integers, I will stick with them for this example, you can add the fractional bits if you understand the reasoning.

The first number has a maximum value of 93, so rounding to the next power of two (128), we need 7 bits.

The first constant is 18, so we need 5 bits.

The result of the multplication will be then 12 bits wide.

The second constant is 320, and we need 9 bits.

Based on these calculations the output needs 13 bits to not overflow.

```
entity temperature is
    Port ( a     : unsigned(6 downto 0);
           b     : unsigned(12 downto 0) );
end temperature;

Architecture Behavioral of temperature is

constant C1     : unsigned(4 downto 0) := to_unsigned(12,5);
constant C2     : unsigned(8 downto 0) := to_unsigned(320,9);

begin
   b<=a*C1+C2;
end Behavioral;
```